# A buggy but effective feature?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Through error analysis I found that a quite effective feature actually has bugs in its implementation. Correcting the bugs actually decreased the classifier's performance.

What do you do? Correct the bugs, or leave them there?

Comment: That might be a bad sign. See [here](http://yudkowsky.net/rational/technical): `Occasionally an AI researcher discovers that if they add noise to one of their algorithms, the algorithm works better. This result is reported with great enthusiasm, followed by much fulsome praise of the creative powers of chaos, unpredictability, spontaneity... But how sad is an algorithm if you can increase its performance by injecting entropy into intermediate processing stages?... If injecting randomness results in a reliable improvement, then some aspect of the algorithm must do reliably worse than random.`

Comment: Anyway, the correct choice is to figure out why the bugs caused the problem. I don't that this question, while interesting, can be constructively answered without much greater detail.

Comment: A not-so-severe bug, could form a kind of regularization, which helps to deal with overfitting. A good example is the random forests. Can you describe what was the effect of your bug on the features ?

Comment: I'd also ask you to spell out how you measure the classifier's performance? As an example, imagine a problem where 85% of the data falls into Category A and only 15% in Category B. You write a classifier which properly labels A's and B's 50% of the time. Then you introduce a bug where you call everything Category A and suddenly your accuracy jumps to 85%!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a stopped clock is correct 2 times a day, a clock that is exactly 2 minutes fast (and consistantly stays 2 minutes fast) is correct 0 times a day.  Which clock will be more useful?

Understanding of relationships and correct future classification are much more important that correct classification of past data.  Unless you believe that the bugs will consistantly improve classification in the future (in which case they become predictors rather than bugs) the fact that they improve the past predictions is more likely due to chance.